# Event onclick not finding element that was fetched through and API with className.include('') cannot read properties of

Tags: javascript, html, css, null, fetch

Hi im building a Survey Web APP

I'm fetching data from an API using Fetch('') javascript now injected to live server on vs code

my expected result is to create a feature that adds an on click event to the feedback list of fetched data and allows you to upvote by 1 then disable it while allowing you to expand the textbox of the survey comment separately my udemy teacher said to use an if statement logical scenario to make this work

issue:
javascript line of code const upvoteIntention = clickedEl.className.includes('.upvote');

is null even tho the API fetched data has been injected live to the server and is present

tried reloading it

using .contain();

putting code under the fetch('') call even tho its aysc

there are a lot of wires and connections but one is cut idk how to fix it please help I need a second brain

```
`//Upvote feature Using Events 

const upVoteClick = (event) => {
    const clickedEl = event.target;

    const upvoteIntention = clickedEl.className.includes('.upvote');

    console.log(upvoteIntention);

    if (upvoteIntention) {
        const upvoteBtnEl = clickedEl.closest('.upvote');

        upvoteBtnEl.disabled = true;

        const upvoteCountEl = upvoteBtnEl.querySelector('.upvote__count');

        // increment 
        let upvoteCount = +upvoteCountEl.textContent;

        upvoteCount = upvoteCount + 1;

        // set upvote count
        upvoteCount.textContent = upvoteCount;



    } else {
        clickedEl.closest('.feedback').classList.toggle('.feedback--expand');
    }

};

feedbackList.addEventListener('click', upVoteClick);






// getting and posting feedback to componet

fetch('https://bytegrad.com/course-assets/js/1/api/feedbacks')
    // converting to json
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        // remove spinner on fetching
        spinnerEl.remove();

        data.feedbacks.forEach(eachItem => {
            renderfeedbackHTML(eachItem)
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        feedbackList.textContent = `Failed to load data: ${error.message}`;
        // customize error with html css connected element stored in js varible 
    });`
```

Comment: `'.upvote__count'` would be ok for `querySelector` and `closest` because they _expect_ a _CSS queries_. For `className` and `classList` you just want to be looking for the _name_ of the class: `className.includes('upvote')` or `classList.toggle('feedback--expand')`

Comment: @Andy Damn bro emotional intelligence is key I couldn't even think hard I was I was mad about it not working If I woulda just looked up the class name and list examples appreciate your time brodie